# SQLite How to know if date column is current month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, date

I have this problem with SQLite, I have the right query in SQL Server but SQLite is differente  I want to know if a Char Column that contains dates can be converted to date and then know and then filter the dates where the month correspond to the current month.

Here's the table with a row of data

[image: Images]

The column that need to know is the current month is FechaCapCalend

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%m', FECHACAPALEND)
```

Returns numeric month where FECHACAPALEND is column of a string date. To compare to current:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN strftime('%m', 'now') = strftime('%m', FECHACAPALEND) THEN 'Yup' ELSE 'Nope' END
```

Comment: This works only if the value uses one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).